# How to connect and access Azure Datalake Gen1 storage using Azure Ad username and password only - c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake, webhdfs

I want to connect and access Azure Datalake Gen1 storage using Azure Ad username and password only.

I have a service account that has access to the Azure Datalake Gen1 storage. I am able to connect and download the files using credentials via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. Also, I am able to connect in SSIS via ADLS Connection Manager and Azure Data Lake Store File System Task.

Now I need to create a console application to connect and perform certain operations (list files and folders and download files)

Searching on google all the results suggest using Azure Ad Application (clientid, tenantid etc.). Unfortunately, I do not have that option.

It looks like in SSIS ADLS Connection Manager uses some kind of WebHdfs connection that supports Azure Ad username and password. But, I am not able to implement something similar in c#.

As usual, running tight on deadlines. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 uses Azure Active Directory for authentication. Before authoring an application that works with Data Lake Storage Gen1, you must decide how to authenticate your application with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

The following table illustrates how end-user and service-to-service authentication mechanisms are supported for Data Lake Storage Gen1.

[image]

**Reference:** [Authentication with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 using Azure Active Directory](http://Authentication%20with%20Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen1%20using%20Azure%20Active%20DirectoryAuthentication%20with%20Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen1%20using%20Azure%20Active%20Directory)

Check out this [Service-to-service authentication with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-net-sdk) using .NET SDK - to learn about how to use the .NET SDK to do service-to-service authentication with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.

For end-user authentication with Data Lake Storage Gen1 using .NET SDK, see [End-user authentication with Data Lake Storage Gen1 using .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-end-user-authenticate-net-sdk).